# Show multiple divs when clicking radio button

Tags: jquery, html

I have some radio buttons that are containing an image:

```
<input type="radio" name="site" id="au" value="1" /><label for="au"><img src="images/auditup.jpg" alt="Audit" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="site" id="ma" value="2" /><label for="ma"><img src="images/repairup.jpg" alt="Maintenance" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="site" id="tr" value="3" /><label for="tr"><img src="images/transportup.jpg" alt="Transport" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="site" id="vi" value="4" /><label for="vi"><img src="images/visitup.jpg" alt="Visit" /></label>
```

i have 6 div's with content

```
<div id="hygiene">
<p>some text</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="achygiene" value="1" id="achygiene" /><label for="achygiene">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
</div>

<div id="security">
<p>some text</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="acsecurity" value="1" id="acsecurity" /><label for="acsecurity">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
</div>

<div id="terms">
<p>some text</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="acterms" value="1" id="acterms" /><label for="acterms">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
</div>

<div id="defence">
<p>some text</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="acdefence" value="1" id="acdefence" /><label for="acdefence">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
</div>

<div id="safety">
<p>some text</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="acsafety" value="1" id="acsafety" /><label for="acsafety">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
</div>
```

What i would like to have is when someone is ticking radio button with id "au" that (f.e.) div hygiene, terms, defense is showing.
but when someone is ticking radio button with id "ma" the divs (f.e.) hygiene and security is showing. and for an other radio button all of the divs are showing. It may not be randomly! so i have to set what divs will open when you tick a radio button. Keep in mind that some radio buttons have the same div's

I'm not good into jQuery at all, so that is why i'm asking for help here.

EDIT:
i have found a lot of examples on stack but not any example with multiple div's

For example this code:

```
$(function(){
    $(':radio').click(function() {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).fadeIn().siblings('div').hide();
    })
    .filter(':checked').click();//trigger the click event
});​
```

I understand the way it works but don't know how to do it if the name of the id's and or classes cannot be the same

Comment: Do you have any existing JQuery code that pertains to this? If so, could you edit your answer with it in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a data-* attribute in each radio to specify the div's to be displayed, like

```
<input type="radio" name="site" id="au" value="1" class="trigger" data-target="#hygiene, #security"/>
<label for="au">
    <img src="images/auditup.jpg" alt="Audit" />
</label>
<input type="radio" name="site" id="ma" value="2" class="trigger" data-target="#safety, #defence"/>
<label for="ma">
    <img src="images/repairup.jpg" alt="Maintenance" />
</label>
<input type="radio" name="site" id="tr" value="3" class="trigger" data-target="#hygiene, #defence"/>
<label for="tr">
    <img src="images/transportup.jpg" alt="Transport" class="trigger" data-target="#hygiene, #security"/>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="site" id="vi" value="4" class="trigger" data-target="#terms, #safety"/>
<label for="vi">
    <img src="images/visitup.jpg" alt="Visit" />
</label>
<div id="hygiene" class="contents">
    <p>some text hygiene</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="achygiene" value="1" id="achygiene" />
    <label for="achygiene">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
</div>
<div id="security" class="contents">
    <p>some text security</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="acsecurity" value="1" id="acsecurity" />
    <label for="acsecurity">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
</div>
<div id="terms" class="contents">
    <p>some text terms</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="acterms" value="1" id="acterms" />
    <label for="acterms">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
</div>
<div id="defence" class="contents">
    <p>some text defence</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="acdefence" value="1" id="acdefence" />
    <label for="acdefence">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
</div>
<div id="safety" class="contents">
    <p>some text safety</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="acsafety" value="1" id="acsafety" />
    <label for="acsafety">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $contents = $('.contents').hide();
    $('.trigger').change(function () {
        $contents.hide();
        $($(this).data('target')).show()
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PC2M2/)

Answer (score 1):

Assign a class to each div naming the radio button that should show it. Elements can have multiple classes, and they don't need to have CSS styles assigned to them.

HTML:

```
<div id="hygiene" class="au ma">
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[name=site]').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = this.id;
    $('div.'+id).show().siblings(':not(.'+id+')').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mjLkR/

You may need to adjust your selectors depending on how your complete HTML is structured.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i am not quit sure which answer is the best this one or the one above but i've used the one above because it looks kind of strange to go the other way (put the class of the radio buttons on the divs). still i will also save your answer!